# Create Toggle buttons in css javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create toggle button with text on it which can be selected and unselected depending on the user. Also I want to color the text in the toggles based on the weights of each text from 1 to -1 going green to red.
Example
[image: Example]

toggle like this which shows the word selected and not-selected.
also if weight of html : 0.7, css :0.5 javascript : 0.1 and jquery: -0.4
the first three terms should appear in shades of green and the term with red

Comment: not sure what you actually trying to achieve. But your vague description seems to me that no scripting language is required. Could be done purely with CSS and HTMl by using checkbox and the `:checked` selector

Answer (score 0):

So i'm going to assume that you want to be able to have a button to swap from green to red. if so, i made a function for it. Here is how you set it up:

1. add a button element with an onclick event and a class`<button onclick='' class=''>JS</button>`
2. add a corresponding class and event `<button onclick='change(/*the number*/)' class='bc/*the number*/'></button>` (the number is how the script will reference the button)
3. add in the styling `<button onclick='change(/*the number*/)' class='bc/*the number*/' style='background-color:rgb(0,255,0)'></button>`

ex. `<button onclick='change(1)' class='bc1' style='background-color:rgb(0,255,0)'></button>`

Code:

```js
function change(c_lass) {
  if ($('.bc' + c_lass)[0].style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
    $('.bc' + c_lass)[0].style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'
  } else {
    $('.bc' + c_lass)[0].style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  outline: none;
  border: 2.5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="change(1)" class="bc1">HTML</button>
<button onclick="change(2)" class="bc2">CSS</button>
<button onclick="change(3)" class="bc3">JS</button>
<button onclick="change(4)" class="bc4">jQuery</button>
```

You don't need the css, but I put it in so it looks nicer and i didnt have to insert a style into every one.